# add number to date(H:mm:ss:SSS) format

Tags: java, datetime

I want to  add date formate(H:mm:ss:SSS).I did the following-

```
    Date time1;
    Date time2;
    String result1;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm:ss:SSS");
    time1 = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,5);
    time2=new Date(0,0,0,0,0,5);
```

the output of time1 is `0:00:05:000`. Now i want to add those two time and make `0:00:10:000`. but `time1+time2` is not possible. is there any way to do this?

Comment: It really doesn't matter how you format your `Date` objects for the output, they are still dates (well, they represent an instant in time, to be more precise). So, what should adding two `Date`s mean anyway? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I need the formatted output. it is not about adding two date. it is about adding two number of this format .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use calendar for your requirement:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,5);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

    System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));

    Calendar another = Calendar.getInstance();
    another.setTime(calendar.getTime());
    another.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    another.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    another.set(Calendar.SECOND,calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)+5);
    another.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

    System.out.println(formatter.format(another.getTime()));
```

OUTPUT:

```
0:00:05:000
0:00:10:000
```

Here is the Java Doc for [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: you answer is right according to my question. actually i want to use a loop which will increase time by 5 sec. in your way, you are adding 5 with second. it would be good for me i could add 5 with the whole date not just with second. Thanks

Comment: Okay. For that you just need to calculate how many seconds you need to add and then just use Calendar to add the seconds.

Comment: i tried with loop and no extra calculation for second is needed. just replaced the "second +5" expression with "second+i" and it automatically took care of minutes and hours. thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

`new Date(time1.getTime() + time2.getTime())` should do the trick.

getTime() returns the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
`new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` equals January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. so you basically only have the milliseconds of the 5 seconds in `time1.getTime()` and `time2.getTime()` so you can just sum these and convert it back to a Date object.